# How to do multiple before_filters on certain Rails Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I looked at the following questions:

- [Are multiple before_action calls bad code style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362946/are-multiple-before-action-calls-bad-code-style/40363411)
- [Api Dock - before_filter](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter)

And I think there was something about creating a controller superclass, but I am not familiar with such.

The reason I need to do this is because, we have a bunch of setup views, and those views are renering a seperate layout. `setup_screen`

So instead of doing

```
  def setup_step_1
     render: layout => 'setup_screen'
   end


   def setup_step_2
     render: layout => 'setup_screen'
   end


   def setup_step_3
     render: layout => 'setup_screen'
   end
```

We created the following:

```
before_action :setup_layout, only: %i[ setup_step_1 setup_step_2
                                       setup_step_3]
```

The problem is, we want to run some extra logic **in the setup_screen's**.  But we can't add another before_filter. It's also not possible to add the logic in the `def setup_screen` because of the case that not ALL setup_screen's will need it.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in those answers, there is no objection to using multiple before-filters. So you can easily add multiple `before_action`. E.g. a typical example

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :get_post, only: [:show, :edit, ...]
```

In your case for the render I would use a `after_action`, since the render is the *last* action. Then you could add your conditionial code in each separate action, or an extra `before_action`.

An alternative method, which I would prefer in your case is something like the following:

```
def setup_step_1
  setup_step(1) 
end

def setup_step_2 
  setup_step(2)
end 

def setup_step_3
  setup_step(3)
end

protected 

def setup_step(step) 
  if step == 1 
    # .. do something for step 1
  elsif step == 2 
  else
  end 
  render: layout => 'setup_screen'
end
```

I would prefer this approach since it is a little more expressive/explicit. Looking at the methods it is clear they share the same core. Personally I prefer to use `before_action` for setting up pre-conditions: e.g. authentication, authorization, fetching the data if very simple.

But as usual in programming, there are a lot of roads leading to a working application and sometimes it is just a matter of taste which you prefer.

Comment: But if I do something like `before_action :do_this only [:setup_step_1]` and I do `after_action :do_that only [:setup_step_1]`, wouldn't only one of the actions get triggered?

Comment: You could easily try this to verify it (e.g. add a log-statement in each), but both would get triggered. `do_this_only` would be called _before_ the `setup_step_1` and `do_that_only` _after_. As said before: you can also specify multiple `before_action` but then the order is undefined, except they will all be called _before_ calling `setup_step_1`.